# PyTorch matrix transformation / concatenation / lookup

Tags: python, pytorch

Let's assume that we have torch.tensor([2,4,3]), and it looks like below.

```
tensor([[[False,   True,  False],
         [False,   True,  False],
         [False,  False,   True],
         [False,   True,  False]],

        [[False,   True,  False],
         [False,  False,   True],
         [False,  False,   True],
         [False,  False,   True]]])
```

In this case, I would like to know if any True exist in each column.
For example for column 0, there's no True, and for column 1, 2, there's Trues.

So what I want to get is a list that [0, 1, 1].

How can I get that without for loop?

The code to get the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first reshape your tensor to a 2D shape, in other words, flatten the columns from the two batches. Then you can use [`torch.any`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.any.html):

```
>>> x.flatten(0,1).any(0)
tensor([False,  True,  True])
```